# Custom href with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to use a custom href from my javascript models so that the back button for each page footer knows where to go.  How would I accomplish this?  Thank you.

```js
 window.APP= {
   models: {
     home: {
       title: 'Home'
     }
     ,
     menu: {
       title: 'Main Menu',
       url: 'views/home.html'
     }
     ,
     cards: {
       title: 'Cards',
       url: 'views/home.html'
     }
     ,
   }
 }
 ;
```

```html
<body>
  <div data-role="layout" data-id="main">
    <div data-role="header">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <span data-role="view-title"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
      <div data-role="tabstrip">
        <a href="views/home.html" data-icon="home">Home</a> 
        <a href="#" data-icon="reply">Back</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Is your back button used to go back to the previous page?

Comment: yes sir; which depends on the page you're on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your back button is used to go back to the previous page, you can use Javascript to accomplish this. `(history.go(-1))`

```
<a href="#" data-icon="reply" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;">Back</a>
```

Comment: simple and effective; thank you; I am new to these languages and am writing an app for work

Comment: what if I wanted a custom href though?  set in my javascript?

Comment: Try adding `return false;` in the onclick.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: it still dumps the emulator; If I could tell href where to specifically go, I wouldn't have any problems.  I am using multiple html files with Telerik

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the contents of a browser's history. Think about it...any website could see anywhere that you've been... that'd be pretty creepy!

Instead, just call this: `window.history.back()`

Answer (score 0):

To go  back use just a call to

```
window.history.back()
```

To go to main page you can call to the root directory.

```
<a href="/"></a>
```

```js
function goBack() {
  window.history.back()
}
```

```css
 window.APP= {
   models: {
     home: {
       title: 'Home' URL: ???
     }
     ,
     menu: {
       title: 'Main Menu'
     }
     ,
     cards: {
       title: 'Cards'
     }
     ,
   }
 }
 ;
```

```html
<body>
  <div data-role="layout" data-id="main">
    <div data-role="header">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <span data-role="view-title"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
      <div data-role="tabstrip">
        <a href="/" data-icon="home">Home</a> 
        <a href="#" onclick="goBack()" data-icon="reply">Back</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```